# New method to accomplish the same functionality as the old Facebook sharer.php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The original method for sharing links with a custom image, text and link appears to have been stripped from Facebook.  I for one would love to see them bring this back.

Here is my situtation.  I have a Facebook tab that loads a page that is hosted under my hosteddomains.com.  I setup a Facebook app to work with my Facebook tab.  When I try to use the new "Share Dialog" if the link I want to share is not the same as the app domains then i get an error and I can't share the link.  Am I doing something wrong or is this what they intended to do?

IF that's what they intended to do then there is no way that this will replace what sharer.php could do.  I could be on any site and share any link with an image to Facebook and have it posted to my wall.

The question is if i am on facebook tab and i want to share a link (I want a dialog box with a custom photo, title, link, and summary) and allow my users to post this custom message to there Facebook status.

Maybe i am confused about how to accomplish this, but so far i am not having much luck.

I miss the good ole days when i could just construct a URL and that would give me the ability to share what i want to share.  Twitter and Pinterest have these methods.

Here are some code examples of things that I've tried that did not work:

**Option #1:** 
The url in this option goes to page that I created on hosteddomains.com that has the Open Graph Meta Tags in it.  My idea was to share these pages from my server that will direct them back to my Facebook tab.  The result I was getting from this method was seeing the title of the tab from my FB page and description.  The reason turned out to be that if i set the og:url to my Facebook tab page, that's the page that would get scraped.  That's not what i was expecting from this method.  I thought it would take the meta tags from the page i shared and the url with it.  Not take all of the info from url and ignore the meta tags.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[URL]"
 target="_parent">SHARE ON FB</a></p>
```

**Option #2:**

Tried using Facebook Share Dialog.  I had an interesting time with this one.  I setup a new Facebook app. I tried the Facebook tab as the URL and also my custom url to the page that has custom open graph meta tags.  The facebook app has two App Domains - hosteddomain.com and websiteA.com.  I also created a Page Tab section.  The page tab section loads the HTML page that was loaded in the tab we made for our facebook page.  Issue with this method is I don't get a custom open graph options set from my php page.  I'm picking up information from the facebook tab again.  At least now the dialog box shows the name of the new app.  I am limited in what i can share using this method.  The url i share has to belong to the App Domains.  In order to have multiple app domains, I had to make that Page Tab section and then add the second url to the App Domains field, otherwise i got a warning.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=[appID]&display=popup&href=[url]
&redirect_uri=[url]&ref=s" target="_blank">SHARE THIS</a>
```

**Option #3**
The last thing I tried was the fb-share-button using the Javascript SDK.  I get the same result as option #1.  I don't think there is much difference between these two.  Option 3 here is a bit easier to deal with and cleaner code.  In this example, the url is to my custom page on hosteddomains.com that has my custom open graph meta tags.  That doesnt seem to matter though.  It still pulls the info from the og:url meta tag.  I tried removing the og:url meta tag.  I get the same result.  Is it the Page Tab info interfering?

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="[url]"></div>
```

Comment: You must put the og-tags on the URL that you are sharing. Setting og:url to something else we will follow that redirect and get og-tags from that page

Comment: so what if I don't have access to the URL that i am sharing, in this case, I am trying to share my Facebook Tab link but i won't have access to the header information because it gets loaded in the iframe.  With the old sharer.php file I could share any url, image, title and summary no matter where that link lived.  I guess I need something similar to that.  THe new share dialog is too restrictive.

Comment: If you don't have access to the URL you can't change the title/image/description and so on. That is by design and there is no way around it

Comment: ok so maybe i can try something else.  How would i create a simple button that when clicked would put a custom message into my status update?  I may be able to accomplish something similar to what i wanted to do originally this way.  I just won't be able to share an image with the message.  Hopeing there is an easy way to do that like there is for twitter and pinterest.

Comment: You are not allowed to prefill the message parameter. The user have to type every single character themself

Comment: hmm, so i can do this with Twitter and Pinterest, but you can NOT do this with Facebook?  Thats horrible.  But thanks anyway for clarifying how limited Facebook is these days.  I still miss the old sharer.php where you could set those params.  @Facebook - can you bring this feature back?

Comment: Just guessing but I don't think we removed it for fun. We most likely removed it because it was misused.